# Is it possible to define a type-safe handle in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to be able to define a type-safe equivalent to a HANDLE or HWND in TypeScript. The use case is instantiating a concrete type which is provided to the user as an opaque type, who's only use is as input to other API functions. Something like the following:

```
 module foo {

    export
        class Handle<T> {
    }

    class Property extends Handle<Property>
    {
        constructor(public value = 12) { super(); }

    }

    export interface IProperty { }

    export function makeProperty(): Handle<IProperty> {
        return new Property();
    }

    export function getPropertyValue(p: Handle<IProperty>) {
        return (<Property>p).value;
    }

}


module bar {
    var s = foo.makeProperty();
    var p = foo.getPropertyValue(12); // this should be a compile error
}
```

I've been encountering 2 issues:

1. You can't return an object of a type you haven't exported. This is why I'm returning the value as an empty interface type.
2. Any value implements the empty interface or empty class. This seems to make it impossible to create a type-safe opaque handle.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

## Why it is not an error

For

```
var p = foo.getPropertyValue(12); // this should be a compile error
```

Its not a compile error since TypeScript uses a *structural* type system instead of a *nominal* type system that you might be used to from C#/JAVA etc.

What this means is that two types are compatible if their *members* (structure) match up irrespective of the *name* (nominal). E.g. the following is okay

```
class Foo{}

var foo:Foo = 123; // okay since number contains everything that a Foo needs (which is nothing)
```

But the following is not okay:

```
class Foo{
    bar:number;
}

var foo:Foo = 123; // Error NOT okay since number doesn't contain member bar
```

## To make it a compile error

Just add some property unique to `Handle` that doesn't exist on invalid types. E.g. I added the property `value:number` below which causes the compile error as expected:

```
module foo {

    export class Handle<T> {
        constructor(public value:number){}
    }

    class Property extends Handle<Property>
    {
        constructor(public value = 12) { super(value); }

    }

    export interface IProperty { }

    export function makeProperty(): Handle<IProperty> {
        return new Property();
    }

    export function getPropertyValue(p: Handle<IProperty>) {
        return (<Property>p).value;
    }

}


module bar {
    var s = foo.makeProperty();
    var p = foo.getPropertyValue(12); // Compile Error
}
```

Comment: Right. My comment could have been worded differently. What I *want* is for that construct (or something effectively similar) to be a compile error. Basically, I'd like to pass an opaque type to the user which I can safely cast back to it's concrete type without requiring an instanceof check. If that's not possible, then it's not possible. But maybe someone else has found a clever way to achieve this with the type system.

Comment: @ChrisColbert see updated answer on `to make it a compile error`

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that there might be a solution which didn't involve tagging the object in some way. Thanks for taking the time answer!